# could not figure out '\u202A' warning while running my opencv code in visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I am continuously getting this warning

Warning 1   warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\u202A' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252) C:\Users\ankitdeora2856\Downloads\opencvFiles\main.cpp  1088

while running my opencv code in c++ in visual studio 2012. My code is building without any errors but this warning is creating issues, not getting the expected output. I am trying to add two images using addweighted() function but not getting the output due to this warning.

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
 double alpha = 0.5; double beta; double input;
 Mat src1, src2, dst;

 /// Ask the user enter alpha
 std::cout<<" Simple Linear Blender "<<std::endl;
 std::cout<<"-----------------------"<<std::endl;
 std::cout<<"* Enter alpha [0-1]: ";
 std::cin>>input;

 /// We use the alpha provided by the user if it is between 0 and 1
 if( input >= 0.0 && input <= 1.0 )
   { alpha = input; }

 /// Read image ( same size, same type )
 src1 = imread("‪pic1.jpg");
 src2 = imread("‪pic2.jpg");

 if( !src1.data ) { printf("Error loading src1 \n"); return -1; }
 if( !src2.data ) { printf("Error loading src2 \n"); return -1; }

 /// Create Windows
 namedWindow("Linear Blend", 1);

 beta = ( 1.0 - alpha );
 addWeighted( src1, alpha, src2, beta, 0.0, dst);

 imshow( "Linear Blend", dst );

 waitKey(0);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Somebody inserted [UTF-8 sequence E2 80 AA](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/index.htm) between " and pic1.jpg, just rewrite this line. Same goes for next line

Comment: Of course, it the actual file names contain those characters, you'll also need to rename the files, or they will not be found.

Answer (score 0):

A UTF-8 character ('\u202A' ) is somewhere in your code but it can't be seen with your current encoding.

I had this issue as well, to solve it I pasted the code into Notepad++ and then at the top under Encoding I changed it to ANSI, the hidden characters appeared and I was able to delete them and paste the result back into Visual Studio.